# Cannot read property 'prototype' of Undefined in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using fast-csv module to handle and parse csv data on my server side. I read the data from the csv file and store the contents in the database. While running from eclipse on local I don't get any errors but if I try to run on AWS server I get the following error.

```
hasIsPaused = !!stream.Transform.prototype.isPaused;
                                ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/imex-research-mass-mailer-v2/node_modules/fast-csv/lib/parser/parser_stream.js:11:37)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/imex-research-mass-mailer-v2/node_modules/fast-csv/lib/parser/index.js:5:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

Initially I thought that there may be some issues of dependent packages not being installed. So I made sure all the packages required by fast-csv are present but still I am getting the error. Please help

Thanks

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: could it be `!!stream.Transform.isPaused`? i.e. without the `prototype` in between `Transform` and `isPaused`? I am not sure.

Comment: @mscdex somehow I had version 0.8 installed. Thanks for pointing out. It works after updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream.Transform` was introduced in node 0.10.  You're probably using a version prior to that on your AWS server.  I suggest upgrading node and then trying again.